# Customize status bar background for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I want a black status bar with white text.
General approach I used is having light style status bar to create a custom black view and to add it to the top of the view controller

```
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, statusBarHeight)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

If the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller I do

```
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -statusBarHeight, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, statusBarHeight)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view];
```

However this seems to be not a very elegant solution, maybe there are better approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that you can do it by adding view on keywindow. It doesn't matter whether your app is running under UINavigationController or under UIViewController. I have did this by making extension of UIStatusBarStyle as below.

```
extension UIStatusBarStyle {
    static func setbackground()  {
        let view  = UIView.init(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Now call this method in appdelegate from method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
UIStatusBarStyle.setbackground()
```

Also, make sure that in your info.plist file you have set

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
Status bar style = Opaque black style
```